# Grouping with HAVING condition

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am having a table of following fields.

[image]

I would like to get output like Status in **only** Invalid_vod within Account_Id group

```
Account_Id  Address_Id  Status
AC001       ADD12345    Invalid_vod
AC003       ADD12348    Invalid_vod
AC003       ADD12349    Invalid_vod
```

I was doing like this but unable to get my intended result.

```
select [Account_Id],[Address_Id],[Status]
  from [DBFile]
  group by [Account_Id],[Address_Id],[Status]
  having [Status] = 'Invalid_vod'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a windowed version of `COUNT` for this:

```
;with cte as (
   select [Account_Id], [Address_Id], [Status],
          count(case when [Status] <> 'Invalid_vod' then 1 end)
          over (partition by [Account_Id]) AS cnt
   from [DBFile]
)
select [Account_Id], [Address_Id], [Status]
from cte
where cnt = 0
```

Answer (score 2):

You can query like this

```
;with cte as (
select Accountid,  count(distinct status) as Distcnt from DBFile
group by accountid
)
select * from DBFile where accountid in (select accountid from cte where Distcnt = 1)
and status = 'Invalid_vod'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH CandidateAccounts AS (
     SELECT Account_Id
       FROM DBFile
      WHERE Status = 'Invalid_vod'
     EXCEPT 
     SELECT Account_Id
       FROM DBFile
      WHERE Status <> 'Invalid_vod' )
SELECT Account_Id, Address_Id, Status
  FROM DBFile
 WHERE Status = 'Invalid_vod'  -- not enough data to be
                               -- sure about this
       AND Account_Id IN ( SELECT Account_Id
                             FROM CandidateAccounts );
```